# Por que o meu $scope.$watch não funciona

Tags: angularjs

Alguém tem ideia por que não funciona o meu `$scope.$watch`, esse modelo `$scope.paciente.telefones` esta ligado a um combobox.

```
$scope.$watch('paciente.telefones', function(oldv, newv) {
    var existeCelularComEnvioSms = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.paciente.telefones, function(tel) {
        if (tel.envioSms == true) {
            existeCelularComEnvioSms = true;
        } else if(existeCelularComEnvioSms == true) {
            tel.envioSms = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Leonardo, por que não está funcionando? Retorna erro, ou algo do tipo? Por favor adicione essa informação na pergunta.

Comment: só uma observação, tá invertido os parâmetros, o correto é: newv, oldv

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa usar o `$watch` passando **`true`** como o terceiro argumento:

```
  $scope.$watch('paciente.telefones', function(oldv, newv) {
    console.log(oldv, newv);
    var existeCelularComEnvioSms = false;
    angular.forEach($scope.paciente.telefones, function(tel) {
        if (tel.envioSms == true) {
            existeCelularComEnvioSms = true;
        } else if(existeCelularComEnvioSms == true) {
            tel.envioSms = false;
        }
    });
 }, true); //<= true (terceiro argumento)
```

De acordo com a [documentação oficial](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch), o terceiro argumento permite ***comparação por valor*** ao invés da ***comparação por referencia***. Da uma olhada no link que passei e pesquisa sobre `objectEquality`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente verificar a mudança de comportamento para aplicar os valores:

```
$scope.$watch('paciente.telefones', function(newv, oldval) {

    if (newv !== oldval) {
        var existeCelularComEnvioSms = false;
        angular.forEach($scope.paciente.telefones, function(tel) {
            if (tel.envioSms == true) {
                existeCelularComEnvioSms = true;
            } else if(existeCelularComEnvioSms == true) {
                tel.envioSms = false;
            }
        });
    }
}, true);
```